# Calculate account size in anchor

Tags: anchor, solana-program, anchor-lang

Which would be the space required for an account containing a struct like the following anchor example?

```
#[derive(AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize)]
pub struct MyStruct {
    subfield: u8
}

#[account]
pub struct MyAccount {
    field: u8,
    my_struct: Vec<MyStruct>, // Allow Maximum 10 items.
}


#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Example1<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = payer,
        space = 8 + 1 + 4 + (10 * 1)
    )]
    pub my_account: Account<'info, MyAccount>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
```

My guess is the following:

```
 + 8 bytes      (Discriminator)
 + 1 byte       (u8 field)  
 + 4 bytes      (Vector) 
 + 10 x 1 bytes (Max 10 items in the vector with size of 1 byte: u8)
```

But I am not sure if using a struct inside an account has additional space requirements. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks right to me. Nested structs just get laid out per their fields with no additional prefixes.

I find this reference quite handy for this stuff: https://www.anchor-lang.com/docs/space